# Run java program with thread

Tags: java, multithreading, server

Good evening, I got this two programs here

**httpServer.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class httpServer extends Thread  {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();


}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0); 
    int theValue = atomicInteger.get(); 
    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        final String response;

        final String requestMethod = t.getRequestMethod();
        if ("GET".equals(requestMethod)) {
            response = String.format("Besuche: %d%n", atomicInteger.addAndGet(1));
        }
        else if ("POST".equals(requestMethod)) {
            atomicInteger.set(0);

            response = "Reset to 0";
        }
        else {
            throw new IOException("Unsupported method");
        }

        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        final OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}



}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
}
}
```

Now i want that the Test.java to start working when i start the httpServer.java.
I want to achieve this with threads. I found this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) online which expalins how i make a thread but i dont know how to get the Test.java to work there.

Note: I know i could write both in one programm but i want to know how to work with threads for another project im working on.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is... could you be more clear? "I want that the Test.java to start working when I start the httpServer.java" (sic) - what? You mean you run `java httpServer` and whatever code is also in Test runs, as well?

Comment: yeah exactly if the httpServer runs, the code in Test should be executed as well

Comment: Then just call `Test.main(<optional parameters>);`. Although this has nothing to do with threads and you've most likely misunderstood something.

Comment: Like i understood threads are programs which run beside the main program or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a thread you need to implement the `run`-Method. Everything inside the `run`-Method will be executed in a new Thread.

You did not implement a run method so the call of `server.start();` does acutally nothing. With a `run`-Method it would look like this:

```
public class httpServer extends Thread  
{
    //Everything inside this method is executed in a new Thread
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        super.run();

        System.out.println("THIS IS EXECUTED IN A THREAD");

        this.serverStuff();
    }

    private void serverStuff()
    {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    }
}

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("THIS IN NOT EXECUTED IN THREAD");

        //This call creates a new Thread. It calls the run()-Method
        new httpServer().start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100515/is-it-possible-to-call-the-main-thread-from-a-worker-thread-in-java) might be useful ! But i think @Kayaman already provided an answer !